# How to group according to a specific key in array with JS

Tags: javascript

I want to sort this array depends on a specific key.

```
const test = [
    {
       id: 1,
       capPrice: 1000
    },
    {
       id: 1,
       twoPrice: 2000
    },
    {
       id: 1,
       twoPrice: 4000
    }
]
```

And I want to get the result as below.
Depends on the specific key, it will sum his own value.

```
const test = [
    {
       id: 1,
       capPrice: 1000,
       twoPrice: 6000
    }
]
```

I tried to make this. But I didn't solve this algorithm yet.
Could you give me some advice? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: This is a group/merge operation, not sorting.

Comment: It would be good if you include your code as well.

Comment: i just tried to solve it without lodash https://jsbin.com/wudequjawa/edit?html,js,console